# Confusion over middleware ordering in express.js?

Tags: express

As I understand things, calling `app.use` on a piece of middleware before a route declaration such as `app.get('/hello')` causes that middleware to be run on a request before it reaches that routing function. My confusion arises when you have a situation with at least three routes and three pieces of middleware, and you want things set up like this:

- route 1 should use middleware A and B
- route 2 should use middleware B and C
- route 3 should use middleware A and C

I am of course missing something, since my current understanding renders such a setup impossible. There is no way to order the statements in the code which would allow such a configuration.

How can this be done? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be easy enough to accomplish. Set it up like this

```
app.use('/route1', middlewareA, middlewareB, (req, res, next) => {})
app.use('/route2', middlewareB, middlewareC, (req, res, next) => {})
app.use('/route3', middlewareA, middlewareC, (req, res, next) => {})
```

When you define the routes like this, the middleware is only applied to the specific route. If you do it like `app.use(middlewareA)` then the middleware is used in all routes after it.

Comment: Ah ha! I hadn't come across this way of declaring things. I didn't realize middleware could be passed as additional arguments to a route, I thought it was a separate line that preceded the route declaration. Thank you.